# Fully Transition from One Gmail Account to Another

Tags: email, gmail

This feels like it should be pretty easy to do, but I can't figure it out for some reason... I am (slowly) moving from my **a**@gmail.com account to **b**@gmail.com. I've got mail forwarding set up, so when I am logged into **b**, I get all of **a**'s (and some other accounts') mail, but I also want to set up a filter & label pair so that any email that goes directly to **a** (and then gets forwarded) is marked with that label. This will work as a reminder for me to go the website that sent me this email and update my account info. 
Only I can't figure out how to set this filter up...

Is this even SO question?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming.

Answer (score 0):

Click on the gear on the top right, and then "settings", and then "labels". Then scroll down and click "Create new label", and then create a name for the label. After that is created, then go to the "filters" tab and then "Create new filter" at the bottom. In the "to" column of the filter, put "a@gmail.com" and then press "Create a filter with this search", and then on the next page, click the box for "Apply the label" and then choose the label you just created.

Voila!